# gridview click events and custom adapter button visibility

Tags: android, gridview, event-handling, click

I am using GridView and applying custom adapter containing CardView as an Item in it. And the Item CardView contains a button like more and has couple of options like GooglePlayMusic tile.
   But when I make the button visible on card item, the GridView item all click events not getting captured. and if I changed the visibility to gone, then the same events works finely.
I am not able to figure out the problem in the code.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView image;
    final TextView title;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        Wing wing = titles.get(position);
        view.setTag(wing);
    } else {
        Wing wing = (Wing) view.getTag();
        wing.getWingName();
    }

    ImageButton more = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.more);
    if (!DashboardActivity.isAdmin) {
        /// *** AFTER HIDING THE BUTTON VIEW, I GOT ALL CLICK EVENTS ***
        more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showManipulationDialog(position);
        }
    });

    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    image.setImageResource(mThumbIds);
    title.setText(titles.get(position).getWingName());

    return view;
}
```

Any suggestions?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the image button takes focus when you click on card item. try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root element in layout

Comment: @Raghunandan, you mean in the GridView?

Comment: in resourceLayout ( row items)